# scrollToRowAtIndexPath not working for UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have  UITableViewController want to scroll when user tap on the bottom of the textfield using scrollToRowAtIndexPath method

// ViewController

```
@interface PersonalInfoViewController : UITableViewController{
}
```

On the textFiled Delegate methods.

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    UITableViewCell *textFieldRowCell = (UITableViewCell *) textField.superview.superview;;
    NSIndexPath* path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:textFieldRowCell];
    [self performSelector:@selector(scrollToCell:) withObject:path afterDelay:0.5f];
}
```

// Scroll Method

```
-(void) scrollToCell:(NSIndexPath*) path {
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:NO];
}
```

**Console O/P**

// Size

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGSize(self.tableView.contentSize));  {320, 711.5}
```

// Bounds

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.tableView.frame)); {{0, 0}, {320, 568}}
```

// IndexPath

```
<NSIndexPath: 0x8e981f0> {length = 2, path = 3 - 0}
<NSIndexPath: 0x8eaa600> {length = 2, path = 3 - 1}
<NSIndexPath: 0x9967d20> {length = 2, path = 2 - 1}
```

So question is that.

- Why tableView not move to particular indexPath in scrollToRowAtIndexPath.
- Where and how to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath.

I don't think so to use scrollToRowAtIndexPath we need to set `contectSize` and `ContectOffset`

Guys check my contect Size and Bounds o/p. How can you say that contect size is smaller than   height

**I found that UITableViewScrollPositionTop working for the top some of the row but not for the bottom of the last 4 to 5**

Comment: Is `scrollToCell:` called? Can you see the log of the path that you put there?

Comment: It will not scroll if your content height smaller than tableview bounds height.

Comment: @NikolasBurk check my question,

Comment: @purrrminator I didn't set the contect height i need to do set contect height?

Comment: please check my question

Comment: Is the textField in footerView?

Comment: No there is no textfield in textView. I have added all the textfield like   cell.accessoryView=txtField;

Comment: Set a breakpoint on `scrollToCell:`.  Is it being called from the UI thread?  If not, that is your problem.

Comment: I think that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37655319/802934) might work in this case too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answer to your question:
Because your content height is smaller than tableview bounds height.

here is working solution if you really need it

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0, textField.frame.origin.y);
    scrollPoint = [_tableView convertPoint:scrollPoint fromView:textfield.superview];
    [_tableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

if you are curious, you can go deeper in the question here : [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

Comment: [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)]; i have set static still is not working

Comment: because tableview can not scroll breaking the bounce edge with `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: please check my question

Comment: @user3772344 try `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];` and `[self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:path atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:NO];` and let me know if it scrolls or not

Comment: I found that UITableViewScrollPositionTop working for the top some of the row but not for the bottom of the last 4 to 5

Comment: @user3772344 It does not works for bottom cells, indeed. Again, because tableview can not scroll crossing the contents bounds.

Comment: Thanks! This worked to solve the problem in my case. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that `tableView's` contentSize is large enough to bring the cell to those positions. In these situations you need to calculate the contentOffset manually for those cells. Try below:-

```
-(void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 CGPoint origin = textField.frame.origin;
CGPoint point = [textField.superview convertPoint:origin toView:self.tableView];
float navBarHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;   
// Adjust the below value as you need
offset.y += (point.y - navBarHeight);
[tableView setContentOffset:o animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: But my question is that why scrollToRowAtIndexPath not working. why its not scrolling to particular indexPath

Comment: Because your content height is smaller than tableview bounds height.

Comment: How contact height is smaller. can tableView automatically not set contact height. I have set static     [self.tableView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 2000)]; still is not working

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in one of my applications.

The general idea is to add a transparent view at the end of the UITableView. 
You can either add a footer or an additional cell.
The height of the view should be: height of the tableView - height of the last visible cell.

Here is the solution I used:

```
- (void)updateFooterHeightForLastTableViewItem:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSInteger sectionNumber = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    CGFloat lastCellHeight = [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:sectionNumber] inSection:sectionNumber]];
    _lastSectionFooterHeight = MAX(0, tableView.frame.size.height - lastCellHeight);
    [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNumber] withRowAnimation:NO];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section  {
    if (section == [tableView numberOfSections] - 1) {
        return _lastSectionFooterHeight;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    CGRect footerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, [self tableView:tableView heightForFooterInSection:section]);
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:footerRect];
    [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [footerView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    return footerView;
}
```